# how to add group into people or group column using jsom/rest

Tags: sharepoint-server, rest, jsom

I want to insert group into list column .how to add share point group into people or group list column using JavaScript or Rest API .

Answer (score 1):

Let's do the REST-approach:

First: Query the group, you want to add:

- URL: https://yoursite/_api/web/sitegroups?$select=Id&$filter=Title -eq 'yourGroupName'
- METHOD: GET
- HEADERS: accept: application/json

I assume, that you have an existing list item, which you want to update with the Group-Id, which you can extract from the previous query:

- URL: https://yoursite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('myList')/items(listItemId)
- METHOD: POST
- HEADERS: accept: application/json, content-type: application/json;odata=verbose, IF-MATCH: *, X-Http-Method: MERGE, X-RequestDigest: theRequestDigestValue
- Data: {"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.MyListListItem"},"PersonFieldInternalName**Id**":groupId}

Please replace yoursite, myList, listItemId, theRequestDigestValue and groupId through the appropriate values.

If you want to update a multiple person field, you have to replace groupId in the last query through {"results":[groupId1,groupId2]}